# How to run an add_action hook for specific page

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I have a function that loads a script for validation and i want to add it for only 'login' page.
this the function:

```
function include_regForm_validation() {
        wp_register_script( 'jQuery_form_validation', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js',array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery_form_validation');

    }
```

I have tried:

```
if (is_page( 'login' )) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_regForm_validation' );
}
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 4):

Put `is_page()` inside the callback function:

```
function include_regForm_validation() {
    wp_register_script( 'jQuery_form_validation', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js',array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    if ( is_page( 'login' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery_form_validation');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_regForm_validation' );
```

WordPress has not determined what page/archive has been requested yet when hooks are added with `add_action()`, so you need to make the determination only when `wp_enqueue_scripts` actually runs, which you do by putting the check into your hooked function.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm.. by the way is there any chance where I can put the `add_action()` to the if condition?

Comment: Not really, for the reason I explained. Why do you need to do it that way?